# How to use inches in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, units

When I edit the guide dimensions it keeps reverting to mm measurement. I just want inches and the document is in inches. How do I stop Inkscape from using the metric system by default?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change both of the settings circled in red to "in".

[image]

When you do that, all measurements will be in inches.

[image]

If you want to make inches your default units, make a new blank document, set the document properties settings to inches as shown above, and overwrite the default SVG file in your inkscape templates folder. I don't know where that is located on a Mac, but in Windows it's located in the program files/inkscape/share/templates folder.

By the way, the metric system is not a just European thing. The whole world is metric, except the US, Liberia, and Burma. And here in the UK although metric is the official system, we also still use the Imperial system.

Comment: Additional info: there exists an inches template already, which you can use by going to File > New from template > default inch.

The 'display unit' setting is the only one that is relevant in this case, the other unit (for the document size) could stay as it is. To truly make the document use inches internally (for use with outside programs that are not respecting the complete SVG standard), you would then also need to change the 'Scale' value to 1 - but this will make the current content of the file change size, so you'd need to resize that.

Comment: @Moini but if you want to create a custom size document in inches though, better to also change the units in the custom size section to inches so the size can be input in inches. Also in my new from template list in Inkscape 0.92.3 there is no default inch template available

Comment: True... I'll edit my comment. Thought that would exist, together with the px and pt ones... :-/ Sorry!

Comment: Editing doesn't work for me... lol. So it's gonna stay there now.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that File > Save Template has a "Save as default template" checkbox, which established a new default.

[image: Safe Template popup]

I made the changes shown above in Document Properties > Page, then "Save Template" and every new doc opens with inches.
[ver. 1.1.2 (2021)]